# Refresh a bean on schedule

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a method to create a security token. The token stays alive for 5 mins.

I then use that token to perform other actions. Since it stays alive for 5 mins, I dont want to create the token on every request. Is expensive.

Instead I wish to reuse it for 4 mins then refresh the call to create a new token.

Thus thought to do it in the following manner.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class Config {

    private final Authorization authorization; // this is a @Component

    public AuthConfig(Authorization authorization) {
        this.authorization = authorization;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixed.delay:PT4M}") // either use a value to pass in else default to 4 mins
    @Bean
    public String getToken() {  // can't actually do this. Method needs to be void
        return authorization.getToken();
    }
}
```

Then use this String in the Component where I need the token.

Like:

```
@Component
public class Manager {

    private final String path;
    private final String token; // coming from above bean
    private final RestOperations restOperations;

    public Manager(
            @Value("${my.path}")String path,
            String token,
            RestOperations restOperations) {
        this.path = path;
        this.token = token;
        this.restOperations = restOperations;
    }

    public Object restCall() {
        // use the token to make a rest call here.
    }
}
```

But it turns out I actually can't use `@Scheduled` to return the value.

Methods using `@Scheduled` needs to be `void`.

Is there way I could schedule this so that I could reuse the token and refresh it every 4 mins?

Doesn't need to use @Scheduled. Just looking for a way to do it.

Comment: What you can do (easy) with your approach: register/replace a bean via `@Scheduled` (without the need to return anything)... But I feel a better way would be via "http session" (timeout of 5 mins;) + "session scope" bean!?

Comment: @xerx593 Not sure if I am understanding this correctly. Do you mean to use SessionScope annotation + server.servlet.session.timeout as mentioned here? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html .  If so won't this affect all my servlet sessions? I only want to schedule this particular token creation.

Comment: nah just "token" brought me into this direction... thanks for clarification

Comment: Next problem: Manager is a singleton bean (and gets token injected....this changes every 5 minutes....but the singleton won't (ever) reinitailized!;)

Comment: `Manager.token` is "state"(ful)..and singletons(`Manager`) shouldn't be!

Comment: except maybe in case of (my proposal for) `Authorization`, where you want it like that + update the value externally/"on demand"/regularly...

Comment: .. :) 5. when the only purpose of `Config` was this and `@EnableScheduling`, then we can also move: `@Scheduled` to `Authorization#updateToken` and `@EnableScheduling` to "any other config" (e.g. spring boot app;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do easily, to work around the return type restriction:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixed.delay:PT4M}")
public void updateToken() { 
    someTokenHolder.setToken(authorization.getToken());
}
```

where `someTokenHolder` would be an (e.g.) singleton bean. (at the costs of replacing `token` with `someTokenHolder.token`).

Without a holder object/bean, we could use spring context directly, e.g. like:

```
@Autowired 
GenericApplicationContext ctxt;

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixed.delay:PT4M}")
public void updateToken() { 
    ctxt.registerBean("token", String.class, authorization.getToken());
}
```

[`GenericApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html)

#### (my) Best (un-over-slept) in your scenario:

`Authorization` (class/object) will be "token holder", whereas the `@Scheduled` job will trigger an update.

1. Refactor `Authorization#getToken` to:

   - rename to `updateToken()`.
   - return `void`.
   - store the token to an instance variable (`token`, instead).
2. Introduce a (plain field) getter for `token`: `getToken()`.
3. In your `Manager` *don't* (constructor) wire the token, but `Authorization` (singleton?), and refer to `authorization.getToken()`  (where you need `token`).
4. Implement the `@Scheduled` as outlined:

   ```java
   @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixed.delay:PT4M}")
   public void updateToken() { 
    authorization.updateToken();
   }
   ```